# Poolparty SPARQL endpoint using java/jersey

Tags: java, rest, sparql, jersey-2.0

I have this curl command that I use to query SPARQL endpoint in [PoolParty](https://www.poolparty.biz/):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html" -d 'format=application/json&query=PREFIX skos:<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> select ?label { <http://thesaurus.iadb.org/publicthesauri/110246602490720414534842> skos:prefLabel ?label .}' http://localhost:8086/PoolParty/sparql/publicthesauri
```

Now I want to do the same query using an Java/Jersey client. My maven dependencies are:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-jetty-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The code that I tried is:

public String getLabels(String query){

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8086");
    webTarget.path("/PoolParty/sparql/publicthesauri");

        Form form = new Form().param("format", "application/json")
            .param("query", query);

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);

    invocationBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.form(form));

    return response.readEntity(String.class));
}
```

This code suppose to do the same call that my curl command is doing, however, with I am able to query the Poolparty SPARQL endpoint if the query, but I am not able to do it with the method, any idea about what I am doing wrong with the method?

Thanks
Luiz

Answer (score 0):

[`WebTarget#path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#path-java.lang.String-) return a *new* `WebTarget` instance.

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8086");
webTarget.path("/PoolParty/sparql/publicthesauri");
```

So your call to `path` here, doesn't set the path on the `webTarget`. It returns a new one. You need to chain the call.

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8086")
    .path("/PoolParty/sparql/publicthesauri");
```